# jquery hide div if youtube embed src is empty

Tags: jquery, youtube, hide

Hi all I want is that a (container) div gets hidden (.videocontainer) when the src="" and display when there is a link in the source. Hope someone can help out with this one

This is the code I'm working on that obviously isn't working:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
                          if ($('iframe[src]').text() === "")
                          $(".videocontainer").hide(

                          });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="videocontainer">
        <div class="thevideo">
            <iframe width="310" height="174" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/860PGF9GXZY" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ( $('iframe[src][src=""]') )
   $(".videocontainer").hide();
else
   $(".videocontainer").show();
```

`'iframe[src][src=""]'` will check that `iframe` has `src` and `src` is empty and if empty hide the `videocontainer` else show the `videocontainer`.

**OR**

```
if ( $('iframe').attr('src').length )
   $(".videocontainer").hide();
else
   $(".videocontainer").show();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($('iframe').attr('src') === ""){
    console.log('11');
  $(".videocontainer").hide();
}
```

Edit: [Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ysKLw/)

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($('iframe').attr('src').length == 0)
$(".videocontainer").css("display","none");
else{
      $(".videocontainer").css("display","block"); 
}
```